# Efficient development process for Golang (or any backend) and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, server, development, web-browser

I am developing a web application. The frontend is a mix between JavaScript and server-side generated html. The backend is written in Golang. Might not be very important, but if somebody made a similar experience with that language, it could be of help.

As of now, everything was written in vim, and "debugged" in the browser (mostly Chrome). As the project gets larger I run into difficulties using my vim-chrome development stack. The backend development is not so hard, because Golang has a nice testing suite, which doesn't need much boilerplate to run. However, the mix between data-driven structs in the Golang templates, the Html and the JavaScript logic are getting somewhat complex:

- I find myself recompiling templates almost all the time when doing frontend development.
- I switch all the time between browser, vim (cygwin), web developer tools of the browser, and reloading pages, making sure caches are cleaned.

So, my question is, how could I make myself more efficient? How should I change my development-testing cycle to make the work more pleasant, especially the switching between server (development) and client (debugging).

(I am not looking for ONE SPECIFIC TOOL. I know this results in stupid answers. I am looking for development approaches, which happen to be accompanied by tools. So, offtopic, but might be interesting: Which tool combination has worked for you, if you ever encountered such a problem, and how did you use those tools?)

Comment: product or service recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Did you even read my whole post? Nevertheless, made some changes...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Consolidate the Golang template compilation and web developer tool debugging into node.js by finding a parser and a DOM emulator. Here are a few:

  - [jsdom - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)
  - [xmldom - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom)
  - [Mya-golang-template | Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.npmjs.com%2Fpackage%2Fmya-golang-template&edit-text=)
- Use JavaScript unit testing and [Selenium tests](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/taxi-rank) instead of running tests  manually
- Use docker to [encapsulate the frontend and backend](https://larry-price.com/blog/2015/05/17/compile-sass-with-docker/) dependencies